# pexpect doesn't see string

Tags: string, pexpect

I'm using pexpect to compare the output from a spawned program. It sees everything I want until it gets to a certain point. Here is what I am looking for:

```
DeviceId 12001055
Waiting to check firmware info..............................
MsgName: Get Firmware Info
DeviceId 12001055
replyList name =  rfm_3.3.0+.bin
name.lower()=  rfm.bin
Elapsed time 173 secs
[12001055] RFU Result: False
```

It sees the 'DeviceId 12001055' and 'Waiting to check firmware info' but after that it see nothing. I'm calling expect with these strings:

```
"%s.+?\r" % 'Waiting to check firmware info'
"replyList name =  rfm_3.3.0+.bin.+?\r"
```

Any thoughts?

Code:

```
def rfu(self, fileName = ''):
    line = CMD_RFU+' '+fileName
    print 'rfu %s' % line
    if self.serial:
        self.serial.wakeUp()
    self.p.sendline(line)
    basename = os.path.basename(fileName)
    basename = basename.lower()
    while True:
        ret = self._confirmFoundPattern("%s.+?\r" % 'Waiting to check firmware info',240)
        break # for whatever reason it doesn't see any strings after the Waiting for...
    cfp = "replyList name = rfm_3.3.0+.bin.+?\r"
    while True:
        ret = self._confirmFoundPattern(cfp)

def _confirmFoundPattern(self, search, timeout=PEXPECT_TIME_OUT):
    ''' Searches output for a particular string. Hoping it was found '''
    # print '_confirmFoundPattern \'%s\' to: %d\n' % (search, timeout)
    if search.endswith("DONT CARE"):
    return
    try:
        self.p.expect(search,timeout)
        #self.logToConsole("Matched String: {}".format(self.p.after))
        print self.p.after
        return self.p.after
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of your actual code, and explain where it doesn't do what you're expecting?

Comment: def rfu(self, fileName = ''):

        line = CMD_RFU+' '+fileName

        print 'rfu %s' % line
        if self.serial:
            self.serial.wakeUp()
        self.p.sendline(line)

        basename = os.path.basename(fileName)

        basename = basename.lower()
        while True:
            ret = self._confirmFoundPattern("%s.+?\r" % 'Waiting to check firmware info',240)
            break
# for whatever reason it doesn't see any strings after the Waiting for...
        cfp = "replyList name =  rfm_3.3.0+.bin.+?\r"
        while True:
            ret = self._confirmFoundPattern(cfp)

Comment: def _confirmFoundPattern(self, search, timeout=PEXPECT_TIME_OUT):
        '''
        Searches output for a particular string. Hoping it was found
        '''
#        print '_confirmFoundPattern \'%s\' to: %d\n' % (search, timeout)
        if search.endswith("DONT CARE"):
            return
        try:
            self.p.expect(search,timeout)
            #self.logToConsole("Matched String: {}".format(self.p.after))
            print self.p.after
            return self.p.after

Comment: Don't know why the <CR> aren't working. It's my first post...

Comment: I've edited the code into your post, guessing at the indentation. Does that look like what you're running? It doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: Well, one obvious thing is that you've got a `while True:` loop at the end of `rfu()` with no `break` - if that's the real code you're running, it will just keep repeating that endlessly, and never get any further.

Comment: Oops left it out on the paste. It's there...

Comment: I'm also not sure why you have `while True:` loops that appear to be designed to execute once and then break unconditionally. But the end of your second pattern has `bin.+?\r` - is there actually anything between the `bin` and the newline? If not, the pattern is wrong and won't match.

Comment: No there isn't. I agree with the While True is not needed. It was a cut and paste form elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Does removing the `.+?` from the end of that pattern make it work?

Comment: I've tried various ways. I'm wondering if it's time. It's 155 seconds before it will see replyList name =  rfm_3.3.0+.bin.

Comment: Ah, that could be it. What have you set `PEXPECT_TIME_OUT` to? That's how long `.expect()` will wait.